# Discord.js | How can I fetch users linked accounts information

Tags: javascript, discord.js, node-fetch

I'm trying to code a bot that fetch data from faceit link user give and compare it with users linked Riot Games accounts username. I want to check if user connected his Discord account to Riot Games account and if it's connected, I want to fetch his/her username to check if it's the same username he/she gave. I couldn't figure out how because as far as I know API is not giving this information to bots. Is there any way to check this?

**Note:** If needed, I'm using node-fetch to request data.

Tried to fetch users linked Riot Games accounts username and compare it with another accounts username whichs connected to Faceit.
Couldn't figure out how to do it since API doesn't give linked accounts of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible through the discord.js library, however it is possible through discord's oauth to get a users connections, this would include the riot games account if one is linked. This of course though means you will have to host some sort of web server to handle oauth redirects.

I recommend reading [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/#a-quick-example) on setting up discord oauth2.

After getting the connection you can store an association between the riot user id and discord id in some database.